# pass bitmap as input to Universal image loader 1.9.3

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I used UIL 1.9.3 in my project to show images. the problem is that I need to show bitmaps and as I know UIL gets String as path of images. how can I set bitmaps instead of string in constants class?

```
public final class Constants {

public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {

"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",  
"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s1024/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s1024/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",

};

 private Constants() {
}

public static class Config {
public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
}

public static class Extra {
public static final String IMAGES = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGES";
public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
}
}
```

in main class:

```
BaseActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(
                Constants.IMAGES.get(position), holder.imageView, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri,
                            View view, int current, int total) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f
                                * current / total));
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Do you understand the point of UIL? No, you can't pass Bitmap into ImageLoader. You can do `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`.

Comment: I load images from server, the only problem is the server sends images in base64 and i should decode it, there is no string path

Comment: Override `BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(...)`. You should return `InputStream` there/ If image is base64 then decode it into image data bytes and return `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: I did not get it, could you explain more please?

Comment: Can you provide the code how you decode Base64 to image data?

Comment: @NOSTRA Is there any option to pass base64 data to imageLoder ? Bcoz I dont have any url to pass in "displayImage" , Or can u suggest me any other method to load images ?

Comment: There is no such option.

Comment: @NOSTRA Is is possible to save image first on sd card and then pass that image path to "displayImage" method ? Right now i have problem of listing bitmaps directly , they changes position.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can pass URIs like "file://..." to `displayImage()` method.